# Sonar seems to compute invalid LCOM4 when dealing with C#5 async methods

Tags: c#, async-await, sonarqube

It seems like Sonar does not compute the correct `LCOM4` value for a class when the class is using async methods.

I have three `async` methods in a class, all accessing/manipulating an identical field in the class, but the `LCOM4` indicates a value of 3, and showing me the three methods.

Indeed the methods, after the compiler transformation for `async` methods, do not share the same field, due to the fact that the method is transformed by the compiler to setup a state machine, and it's the state machine, in another method that actually holds the code of the original method.

Anyway, could anyone confirm that Sonar does not correctly compute `LCOM4` when dealing with C#5 `async` methods? Is there any already existing fix for this or is there one planned?

*EDIT*

Here some code sample :

Here is the non async version of a very simple class :

```
public class LComNonAsync
{
    public bool State { get; private set; }

    public void Enable()
    {
        this.State = true;
    }

    public void Disable()
    {
        this.State = false;
    }
}
```

And here is the async version :

```
public class LComAsync
{
    public bool State { get; private set; }

    public async Task EnableAsync()
    {
        await Task.Yield();
        this.State = true;
    }

    public async Task DisableAsync()
    {
        await Task.Yield();
        this.State = false;
    }
}
```

Once ran through Sonar, if I take a look at LCOM4 for both of these classes, here is what I can see :

For **LComNonAsync**:

> > Lack of Cohesion of Methods: 1
> >
> > > 1 State (property)
> > >
> > > System.Void Disable()
> > >
> > > System.Void Enable()

And for **LComAsync**:

> > Lack of Cohesion of Methods: 2
> >
> > > 1 System.Threading.Tasks.Task EnableAsync()
> > >
> > > 2 System.Threading.Tasks.Task DisableAsync()

I put an `await` statement in the `async` methods but I am sure that even without the await the problem will be present. The sole fact that the methods are flagged as `async` are triggering the `async` compiler transformation of the methods. After compiler transformation, from an IL point of view, as I said before, the public methods body will be replaced by the setting up of a state machine / launching the state machine, and the actual original code of the method will be placed in the MoveNext method of this state machine. Therefore the "State" property is no longer referenced in the original public methods, and LCOM4 "violation" is triggered.

In fact, this is not the only problem I got with Sonar and C#5 async/await. We have started a huge project relying heavily on async/await constructs of C#5, and had to integrate our project in Sonar because the company wanted us to (just discovered Sonar a few days ago, it kicks ass ... despite the fact that for certains things C#5 is not correctly supported ... anyway). 
Other problem I face are with static code analysis. We had to disable Gendarme because it raises a lot of totally false positives for certain rules, due to async method transformation by C#5, and for other rules due to the usage of Tasks ... so we decided to rely on FxCop, but FxCop10 is offfered in the C# Sonar ecosystem but it does not takes .NET Framework 4.5 / C#5 in consideration either, so we would go with FxCop11 which correctly support C#5 however it is not available as a standalone version -yet?- and it seems to be a pain in the .. to take it from visual studio 2012 and put it as standalone on the analysis machine ... anyway, code analysis is a totally different concern and not relayted to the LCOM4 problem at all, but that was just for sharing ;)

Comment: Could you please provide some sample code?

Comment: @ppapapetrou : sorry for the late edit, but here it is, some code sample !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the time of this writing, due to the lack of answers and my testings, I consider that Sonar does not work correctly with C#5 async/await constructs when computing LCOM4.